# I don't think you should have done that

Tags: meaning, negation, auxiliary-verbs, placement

a. I don't think you should have done that.

b. I think you shouldn't have done that.

c. I don't think you should go there.

d. I think you shouldn't go there.

Is there any difference between the meanings of (a) and (b)?

Is there any difference between the meanings of (c) and (d)?

It seems to me that the answer to both questions is 'no'. I think (a) and (c) are more natural. I don't think context makes any difference here.

Comment: I think you are quite right. There's no difference between the meanings but (a) and (c) are more natural. We usually say "I don't think..." It is clear and more emphatic than "I think you shouldn't...", which is so unusual that the other person might ask for clarification: "I should or I shouldn't?"